# How to make my phpmyadmin (yii2 code) understand foreign languages?

Tags: phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows'=>20,'columns'=>100,'maxlength' => 4000]) ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Add') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

this is my view. if i run the code and try to insert a value in the form field 'description' in my local language like this (വിനീത്) the value that gets stored is " ????? ". how can i store the value as (വിനീത്) itself and display it in the view.

as said by @Akhil Thayyil i tried like this in my view

```
<div class="synopsis-form col-md-5">
    <h2><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h2>



    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( [
                'method' => 'post',
                'id'     => 'add-fanclub',
                'accept-charset'=>'UTF-8'
                ] );?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows'=>10,'maxlength' => 1000]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

but i got a error like this `Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveForm::accept-charset`

my main-local.php in common/config (yii2 advanced app)is as follows

```
'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_urshow',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'user',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

Comment: താങ്കളുടെ mysql database encoding is wrong .. :-) 
Correct this, also in yii2-backend configure db to use utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. i went to phpmyadmin selected the table and set the property 'collation' to utf8_general_ci and now i can insert ജിലെബി and it will get stored in database as ജിലെബി and i can view in my website as ജിലെബി itself.

[courtsey](http://www.ratheesh.in/php-my-admin-malayalam-issue-solving-utf-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Configure db in yii to use utf-8 character set.
Also create your database with any supported wide character encoding

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

Also ensure that your html form is utf-8 aware :

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
</form>
```

And add this meta information to for your browser to handle utf-8 :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: this is my components    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_urshow',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'user',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this link:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode/
Hope this works for you.

Comment: its yii1 i want a solution for yii2

Comment: you need to do nothing with the phpmyadmin just look for database connection in this above link. And did you added this in your php.ini file:mbstring.func_overload "7"
mbstring.internal_encoding "UTF-8"

Comment: there is no php.ini in yii2

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Please visit this link for yii2:https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-i18n.md